# How to get a Date ddMM from integer with java.util.formatter?

Tags: java, date, csv, formatter

I have to convert two integers usign java.util.formatter into a Date formatted as ddMM.

This is an extract of my properties file loaded by the batch in charge of the transformation.

```
 CAH_PARACL_JJMM5=format('%02d%02d',9.CAH_PARACL_JJMM5_1,9.CAH_PARACL_JJMM5_2)
```

The application's purpose is to convert this data according the properties file to a CSV File.

But when I open the CSV, for example I should get for the march 6th; 0603, but I get 603. The first 0 is missing.
But for the march 13th, I get a good response 1303.

For a test, I have try to add a special character like "/", and when my format is contening this slash :

```
 CAH_PARACL_JJMM5=format('%02d/%02d',9.CAH_PARACL_JJMM5_1,9.CAH_PARACL_JJMM5_2)
```

In the CSV file, the Date is well write : 06/03

But this CSV must be upload by our client, so we can only have numbers in the result...

Thank you.

Comment: I guess the problem is in creating the CSV. The column seems to be interpreted as number and thus leading 0s are removed. Can you configure so that the column is interpreted as string? See, when you put in the "/" - that will break any attempt to interpret the data as number and the conversion will probably fall back to string.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
At the moment, I just get a look at the format colum but it's yet string. And in the CSV which is generated, when I open it with a text editor I've got the same problem.

Comment: How do you generate the CSV? Do you have control over the code of the conversion application?

Comment: It wasn't my job until now, I will try to find the sources :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a problem coming from the code: delete le first zero...

Comment: Most CSV formats allow double quotes around fields. The following is just a thought, but may be worth trying. If you put "0603" (with quotes) into CSV, will the customer see 0603 (as desired), or will s/he see "0603" with the quotes (which probably isn’t acceptable)? Are you in a position where you can have a dialogue with the customer about it?